# Pegar id de um select dinamico com o jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso pegar o id Bairro3, estou fazendo assim

```
$(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
        var bairroID = $(this).val();
```

mas mesmo assim nao funciona.

Tem que acrescentar uma variavel no #bairro, para cada formulario que abrir tenha um id diferente #bairro1 #bairro2 #bairro3..., como posso fazer isso, imagino que teria que fazer isso para o id #rua também #rua1 #rua2 #rua3...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
        var myID = $(this).val();
        $('.panel').each(function(){
            myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            console.log("ok");
        });
    })


    $(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
        var bairroID = $(this).val();

        if(bairroID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_data2.php',
                data:'bairro_id='+bairroID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#rua').html(html);
                    console.log("ok");
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#rua').html('<option value="">Select categoria first</option>');

        }
    });

});
```

Html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label for="Planos">Planos</label>
<select name="Planos" id="sectionChooser" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <option value="1">Diamante</option>
   <option value="2">Ouro</option>
   <option value="3">Prata</option>
   <option value="4">Light</option>
   <option value="5">Free</option>
   <option value="19">Link</option>
</select>
<div class="panel" id="1" style="display: block;">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label><b>Diamante</b></label>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <label for="Bairro">Bairro</label>
   <select class="form-control valid" name="bairro" id="bairro3" required="" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <option value="1">teste bairro</option>
      <option value="2">teste bairro 2 3</option>
      <option value="3">ação bairros</option>
      <option value="4">Centro</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <label for="Rua">Rua</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="rua" id="rua" required="">
   </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Conforme falei no chat, Vc não precisa criar vários ids... basta criar names com arrays, tipo name="bairro[]"... e vc consegue pegar o valor de cada uma com `$(document).on('change', '[name^="bairro"]', function(){ var bairroID = $(this).val();`

Comment: Não olhando muito a fundo na sua questão, id's crescentes quase nunca(senão mesmo nunca) é o que você pretende, mas sim classes(todos com a mesma), ou uma solução como o @dvd indicou.

Comment: Acho que você poderia ter se concentrado na outra questão que é quase a mesma coisa desta, aí vc já resolveria tudo

Comment: É óbvio que se você usar o seletor por ID como aqui `$(document).on('change', '#bairro'` o resultado sempre será **"bairro"**. Por que não faz um seletor por nome, ou tipo de tag ( `select`, `input`, etc) ou ainda por classe?

Answer (score 0):

Ficou assim o código, funcionou

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
        var myID = $(this).val();
        $('.panel').each(function(){
            myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            console.log("ok");
        });
    })


   $(document).on('change', '[name^="bairro"]', function(){ var bairroID = $(this).val();
        console.log("ok");

        if(bairroID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_data2.php',
                data:'bairro_id='+bairroID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#rua[name^="rua"]').html(html);

                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#rua').html('<option value="">Select categoria first</option>');

        }
    });

});
```